# JSP page yes/no dialog box

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, dialog

I have three fields on JSP Update page userid, name and ssn.. I would like to have simple dialog box saying "You already have ssn, are you sure you want to modify it?" depending on the user's yes or no response than it performs the task? Is there a way I can add something on my java code to make this happen.. any help would be great.. thank you..

Answer (score 3):

You should use java script for this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var response = confirm ("You already have ssn, are you sure you want to modify it?")
    if (response){
      //do yes task
    }else{
     //do no task
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I cannot use javascript for this.. i am doing all my checking under javabean.java using switch case.. for rest of my fields like userid and name it doesnt allow me to change.. if duplicate exists but for ssn i would like to have dialog box which gives warning and let them change it if they chose yes

Comment: I have no idea why you can't java script here. It will have to be done on the client side. Once you get the information do a form submit or ajax call (whatever makes sense in your use case) to pass the data back to your java bean.